# Is my i7 920 Intel processor considered ia64 or x64?

Tags: cpu-architecture

Is my i7 920 Intel processor considered ia64 or x64?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

ia64 is a reference to the relative flop that is [Itanium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itanium).

The i7's use x64, aka: amd64 or x86-64, or Intel 64 (EM64T). They all refer to essentially compatible 64-bit extensions. For more info on those, check [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64)

Comment: Too bad about the ia64 architecture.  Really slick.  If it (and the required compilers) got the kind of development that we keep dumping into x64, I believe we'd all be better off.  :-(

Answer (score 11):

x64

ia64 refers to Itanium based designs and their brethren.

Answer (score 3):

x64.  ia64 is the Itanium architecture which is found mostly on enterprise class servers.

Answer (score 1):

In layman terms, current itanium is IA64.  It can only run 64 bit.  I7 is x86-64, can run both.